# Help me find a PWM IC (DP91 1L15 marking)

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, identification

I found this 6 pin PWM IC in one of the SMPS. I am unable to find any of its details on Google. Can anyone help me find the name of the device?

The marking is something like `DP 91 1L 15`.

Comment: Please add a high resolution photo of the IC and surrounding parts. _"is something like"_ doesn't sound too confident.

Comment: Why did you edit the title? If you want a different part identified, please open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markings match with a [Shenzhen Developer Microelectronics (德普微电子) DP2291](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2202171030_Shenzhen-Developer-Microelec--DP2291_C2967752.pdf) PWM controller.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [szlcsc.com](https://item.szlcsc.com/3360177.html)